# In Linux using env command does not work on u+s file

Tags: linux, chmod

I'm new in Stack Overflow,maybe my question descripe is complex, sorry for that.

I was compiled a C++ program to a binary executable file `mygraph`

Then I use `sudo chmod u+s mygraph` to give it a "set uid permission",The file owner and group is root:root,I use a normal user `ezeta` to execute `mygraph`.

mygraph need a LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment,So I use env command to execute `mygraph`,but it doesnt work because system prompt `./mygraph: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I think it because env command does not work.
Here is the start command:

```
$ env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./bundle/lib:./bundle/jre/lib/amd64/server ./mygraph
./mygraph: error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$
$
$ ll .
 total 272
 drwxrwxr-x  9 ezeta ezeta    4096 Jan  8 11:35 ./
 drwxrwxr-x  7 ezeta root     4096 Jan  8 14:01 ../
 drwxrwxr-x  4 ezeta ezeta    4096 Jan  6 16:26 bundle/
 -rwsrwxr-x  1 root root 205384 Jan  8 14:01 mygraph*
```

mygraph permission is rws rwx r-x,I know I run mygraph with ezeta will have root permission beacause s permisson.But maybe the env command sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH to `ezeta` instead of `root`.

How can I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to `root` by user ezeta with env command or other way?

ps:I cant use -rpath to write LD_LIBRARY_PATH in ELF header,because I need prevent this path being tampered.

Comment: Well, where *is* this libjvm.so located?

Comment: in the "bundle" at the same path with "mygraph",you can see at the prints of ll command

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the suid permission are not the way you need them. Why don't you call mygraph with sudo?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly，that because I need the files that mygraph writes can not be root permission,But I need to read board_serial in /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/ so I need root permission.